# How to send upload file in the request in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, request, react-redux

I am using FileBase64 component from react-file-base64 for uploading files. When i tried to invoke from postman it is working
[image: from the postman it is working.]

But when i tried to invoke the same from UI it is not working

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import BASEURL from './urlConfig.jsx';
//import dispatcher from "../dispatchers/dispatcher";

module.exports ={

_callAPI: function(url,method,data,target){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: method,
        data: data,
        processData: true,
        contentType: "multipart/form-data",
        success: (data,textStatus, jqXHR) => {
            target('success', data);   

        },
        error: (jqXhr,textStatus,error) => {
            target('error',jqXhr,textStatus,error);
            console.log("error inside code", jqXhr,textStatus,error);
        },

    });
},

}



<div className="col-sm-7">
                            <FileBase64
                            multiple={ true }
                            onDone={ this.getFiles.bind(this) } />
                            <div>
                            { this.state.files.map((file,i) => {
                            localStorage.setItem("uploadFileName", file.file);
                            return
                                <img key={i} src={file.base64} style={{maxWidth: "150px", margin: "15px"}}/>
                            }) 

                            }
                            </div>
                            </div>
```

for filebase64 component i am using below component.

It is treating as text instead of file in the key and value pair from the UI.
the same if i use with postman with file it is working is this the right way o pass file using multipart form data or in the request we need to specify anything for upload as file